# Modelica: add a row and column in 2d array

Tags: arrays, interpolation, modelica

I have a 2d array of calculated values (say z) in a Model and want to use CombiTable2D from MSL to interpolate for given values of `xi` and `yi`. The CombiTable2D documentation suggests that the first row and column needs to be `x0, x1, .. xi, ..xn` and  `y1, y2, .. yi, ..yn`.
For example, if the array is:

```
[z11, z12;    
z21, z22]
```

To interpolate using CombiTable2D the array has to be of the form:

```
[0, x1, x2;   
y1, z11, z12;   
y2, z21, z22]
```

Therefore I want to add a row and column to the existing array to pass it as a table to CombiTable2D. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You append to an array by putting the row (with ";") or column (with ",") and the array you want to append to inside square-brackets []. An example which solves your problem:

```
example = [1,2;2,3];
newRow = [1,2];
addRow = [newRow;example];
newCol = [0;1;2];
addCol = [newCol,addRow];
```

Output:

```
addRow =
[1, 2;
1, 2;
2, 3]
addCol = 
[0, 1, 2;
1, 1, 2;
2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I had 'higher than the declared variability of the variables' error for using the CombiTable2D in the way I described in the question. But that is a separate issue. Above solution worked as intended. Thanks!